# Azure Data Factory On-Premises Copy Error

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to schedule an on-premises copy job that contains a SQL Server.
 However I am getting a different kind of error when trying to enter the sql server credentials.

> Type=Microsoft.Data.Mashup.InternalMashupException.Message..sorry,en
>   error occurred during
>   evaluation.,Source=Microsoft.Data.Mashup"Type=Microsoft.Mas..data
>   protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by
>   not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user
>   context which may be the case when the thread is
>   impersonanting.Sources, "Type=Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluation.Inter...

I have provisioned the gateway onto the server where the sql server is hosted but getting this error.

Also I am using the Copy Preview feature to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but it looks like an authentication issue. Have you tried connecting to the server from the gateway? Open the Microsoft Integration Runtime Configuration Manager, go to Diagnostics and fill every field, then click test. If everything is correct, a green check should appear. You are trying to impersonate a user, so choose Windows instead of Basic.

Try with it until you get the green check, then make sure that the linked service you are using has the same info you used and it should work.

You can also try creating a database user and give it permissions to make the query you want, then changing the linked service to use the database user instead of the windows user.

Comment: I can see the green tick from the portal onto the gateway so I think its provisioned successfully, and in on permise I am using the SQL authentication feature

Comment: The green check on the portal shows that the gateway is online, but that doesnt mean the linked service is configured correctly to access the database. Go to the pc where the gateway is installed and follow the procedure I gave you on the first paragraph.

Comment: How the linked service is linked with all of this, I am using the Copy Preview feature, So I dont know whats the Linked service for??

Comment: The gateway itself doesnt store any credentials, so it needs to read them from the linked service. In the portal, go to Author and Deploy and you will be able to see the linked service, click on it and it will show the json where the connection string and the credentials are stored. Check if they are correct

Comment: I can only see the IR Gateway into the Linked service thing. Inside Author and deploy it says no linked services.

Comment: So you mean to say I need to update the Gateway Properties inside the pc to use same set of credentials.

Comment: I think the linked service creates when the copy process been initiated from the source and to the destination. In my case I am getting the error when trying to enter the source server details so its never getting provisioned. So how come the linked services will generate any JSON??

Comment: can I not create linked services JSON inside the portal?

Comment: At this point my recommendation is that you read and study more about data factory. The documentation is there for you, learn the basics and go to my original answer, as I'm quite sure it is the answer you need but you don't know how to understand it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-introduction

Comment: Ok I'll try the above fix and let you know if the issue can be resolved, meanwhile I'll try to lear about Azure Data Factory as Much as I can.
I'll mark this as an answer if this will work.

Comment: I dont understand between the authentication type basic and Windows, as in copy activity we have windows and sql, and I am using SQL Authentication.

Comment: What if I am using an SQL Authentication? What to do in that scenario.

Comment: I know how to use Data factory using Copy Preview Feature but haven't tried using the template feature, If you can help me in resolving this using the Copy Preview feature that will be helpful.

Comment: Basic authorization means that you are accessing the database with a database user, Windows means that you are using a windows user credentials to access the database. I dont know what template are you talking about.

Comment: How to write the json for the linked service using sql authentication?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-sqlserver-connector#linked-service-properties Scroll down a bit and look at the samples, there is one for using sql auth and one for using win auth.

Comment: I just created the linked services with the same credentials that I am using in my PC also I have checked the diagnostics setting with the same credentials but I am still getting the same error in the Copy(PREVIEW) feature.

Comment: Dont use copy preview feature, it just automates some of the work for you. Try to create the json files, there are a lot of tutorials in the documentation. Where are you reading the data from and where do you want to write it?

Comment: Am reading it from On Premise and transfering it to the Azure Data Warehouse or Blob Storage

Comment: I am getting the below error while starting the pipeline:-

Copy activity encountered a user error at Source:SQL side: Integration Runtime (Self-hosted) Node Name=SQL,ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToConnectToSqlServer,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot connect to SQL Server: 'SQL', Database: 'dev', User: 'test'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Message=The user name or password is incorrect,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'.

Comment: The user name or password is incorrect, the error message is clear. If diagnostics is working, then change your connection string to match that.