# How to use truncate in Copy Preview to Truncate various tables

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can I use a truncate command to truncate all the values inside multiple tables? And how to pass this inside the Copy Preview feature?

How to copy the latest blob to Azure datawarehouse using copy preview?

I have various tables in various folders with multiple amounts of data. How can I write JSON to only copy the latest data to Azure datawarehouse?

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel like you've tried very hard here and are expecting free dev work.

The copy wizard in ADFv1 is only for a very specific purpose and isn't very good. You won't be able to use it for more complex things like you describe above.

I recommend you open up Visual Studio 2015, load an ADFv1 project and start figuring out what JSON you need.

There are plenty of resources out there to use to develop complex data factory pipelines.

Comment: I've given up trying to help this guy, watch the comments on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082633/azure-data-factory-on-premises-copy-error

Comment: Am not expecting any thing..all I want is the right direction

Comment: @MartinEstebanZurita I did everything you said and that hasnt resolved my issue 1 bit, have told my previous issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082633/azure-data-factory-on-premises-copy-error) to microsoft and they have said that this is a bug in the data factory, not sure what you talkin about HELP here???

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need by modifying the sqlReaderQuery  property inside your pipeline. It was nicely explained here by g_brahimaj [Execute storedProcedure from azure datafactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903441/execute-storedprocedure-from-azure-datafactory/47905719#47905719) do the same, but change the exec command for the truncate command that you need.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I figured it out anyways